# Query for total earnings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table 'collection'. It stores the sales from 2 shops in the form of cash and card:

```
Date        |  Shop | Cash | Card |
-----------------------------------
2017-01-01  |   A   |  10  |  5   |
2017-01-01  |   B   |   8  |  2   |
2017-01-02  |   A   |   9  |  6   |
2017-01-02  |   B   |   8  |  5   |
2017-01-03  |   A   |   9  |  7   |
2017-01-03  |   B   |  10  |  1   |
```

I want to run the SQL query and get the total daily earning from the two shops as the following output

```
Day    |   Earnings
-------------------
1      |   25
2      |   28
3      |   27
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  I should note that your sample data has only two days.

Comment: The sample data has two different dates, but the result three different dates. Please, have matching data.

Comment: sorry, corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be easy with a simple `GROUP BY` like:

```
   SELECT Date
         ,SUM(Cash + Card) AS Earnings
     FROM yourtable
 GROUP BY Date
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Check as below :

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by date) AS Day
         ,SUM(Cash + Card) AS Earnings
     FROM #TEMP
 GROUP BY Date
```